# mp4 that can be played using Quicktime on PC but not on Mac

Tags: video, mp4, quicktime, movie, mpeg-4

I have couples of .mp4 files, all of them can be opened and played using QuickTime Player 7.7 installed on PC.

But some of them cannot be opened using QuickTime Player 10.1 on Lion.

It said "The document xxx.mp4 could not be opened. This media may be damaged."
And these unplayable files cannot be played on iPod too.

All files are converted in same way in same format.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a codec issue. Can you open them on the Mac using VLC? Try to install Perian, then Quicktime should be able to play the videos.

http://perian.org/

Comment: but my goal is to play these videos on iPod. these videos are supposed to be play with an App.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: iDevices are picky about codecs. You will have to transcode the video-file to a format the iPod can play. If you are lucky the codec is fine and only the container is wrong. Then you only need to change the header without re-encoding. Try a tool like iFlicks for this.